# Python lambda functions, iterating over a tuple and a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Suppose you have a class Table which contains the attribute:
records (list of dictionaries)
and keys which is the primary key of each table (just like SQL) - Tuple

I need to write a lambda function that takes a new row and then spit out True or False if all the values of the keys in the new row
are already in the table

For example:

```
# Table: orders

keys = ('product_id', 'customer_id')

records: [{'product_id': 51, 'customer_id' : 10, 'units':9},
          {'product_id': 32, 'customer_id' : 11, 'units':33},
          {'product_id': 39, 'customer_id' : 47, 'units':2}]
```

and now the new row we want to check is:

```
{'product_id': 51, 'customer_id' : 10, 'units': 77 }
```

This would return `True` because `product_id==51` and `customer_id==10` just like the first dictionary in the record (the units does not matter, because its not a key).

However this:

```
{'product_id': 51, 'customer_id' : 11, 'units':9}
```

Will return `False` because there is no row with `product_id==51` and `customer_id==11`

We must use lambda functions (we don't have to use filter, just a hint)
I've tried many many different ways of 'attacking' this question, but I couldn't iterate over a list of keys and a tuple at the same time...

```
contains_key = lambda self, new_row: list(filter(  
  (lambda con: con[self.__key]), 
  [record for record in self.__records] 
))
```

Explanation: self is the table we do the operation on, new_row is the row (dictionary) to check
self.__keys is the tuple of keys (like primary keys in sql) and self.__records is the list of dictionaries="""rows in an sql table""")
The function is inside the class Table  (that's why it's in the "self" form)

```
class Table:
    def __init__(self, key_set):
        self.__key = tuple(key_set)
        self.__records = []

    def add_record(self, new_record):
        self.__records.append(new_record)
```

Comment: *"need to write a lambda function "* - Why?

Comment: doing `x = lambda ...` kinda loses the point of lambdas...

Comment: @HeapOverflow
It's a university task. I have no idea why would you use lambdas is such an awful way, and they actually said it in the task (it's just to explain how to write it)

Comment: I'm assuming this is some kind of assignment for a CS or programming class and this is why you're trying to write this as a lambda. This is actually an anti-pattern in normal Python programming, you shouldn't assign a lambda to a name, in that case a `def` is almost always better.

Comment: @Grismar Correct sir. :)

Comment: You're referencing `self.__key` in the example, but there's no code showing the structure of the class you're operating on. Can you share it (or the relevant bits anyway)? Or is `self.__key` identical to your `keys` (in which case I would suggest just putting that in the examples).

Comment: FWIW, all python programs can be converted to one line using lambda functions: https://onelinepy.herokuapp.com/ . There's also `eval`, or using `;` to separate statements, but that's kinda cheating and discourages you from making fancy y combinators. ;)

Comment: I *highly* doubt they mean it the way you're interpreting it. Can you show the text that you think says so?

Comment: @Grismar keys hold the names of the keys in the dictionary which are the primary keys of the table.  The structure is only initializing orders to be an empty list and keys to a tuple , when you create a table you specify the keys such as:  
a = Table('product_id', 'customer_id')  and then there's a function which adds records (dictionaries) to the records list

Comment: @Grismar i've updated the question, i added the implementation of table (some of it, I think the most important parts at least)

Comment: @Tomerikoo Hi, Sorry for this surprising question. 
Why is assigning x = lambda loses the point of lambda? I understand what is a lambda but what does the x= do?  Just to  expand my knowledge. Thank you!

Comment: It's not that it does something wrong. Is just that the idea of lambda is unnamed function. In the end it created a function object just like def. But you can put lambda in-line and use for example as arguments to other functions (and you don't need to use them anywhere else)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple use of [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) will do the trick: *"check if `all` keys of `any` record are the same as the new record"*:

```py
print(any(all(new_record[key] == record[key] for key in keys) for record in records))
```

The good thing with those functions is short-circuiting: whenever a key doesn't match - the record will be skipped, and when a record is matched - no more records will be checked.

---

I will leave it to you as an exercise to turn that into a `lambda` :)

Comment: Hi, If there is a dictionary in the orders like so: order3 = {'customer_id' : '13','product_id' : '1234-5', 'units': 9 }  and we test it with another dictionary:

order4 = {'customer_id': '13', 'product_id':'1234-5', 'units':3}  
The final answer is "False" and should be True, I have no idea why it looks OK to me though.

Comment: Wait, my bad. it works totally fine. Thank you very much and when I read this function I now understand clearly the pattern. many many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a canonical answer to start with:

```
def has_row(records, keys, row):
    return any(
        all(row[k] == x[k] for k in keys)
        for x in records
    )
```

---

The conversion to a "lambda function" is trivial:

```
has_row = (lambda records, keys, row:
    any(
        all(row[k] == x[k] for k in keys)
        for x in records
    )
)
```

---

If you're not "allowed" to use `any` or `all`, they can be replaced as follows:

```
any = (lambda xs:
    bool(next(filter(lambda x: x, xs), False))
)

# Alternatively, without using next:
any = (lambda xs:
    len(list(filter(lambda x: x, xs))) != 0
)

all = (lambda xs:
    len(list(filter(lambda x: not x, xs))) == 0
)
```

Comment: @HeapOverflow Whoops can't believe I ordered those wrong after writing some Haskell recently...

Comment: @HeapOverflow You mean like `filter(None, xs)`? Neat trick to remember, but I'll leave it like this for the OP who's already a bit confused. ;)

Comment: Yes, I meant `None`. Another idea: `all = lambda xs: min(map(bool, xs), default=True)` and `any = lambda xs: max(map(bool, xs), default=False)`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, it seems:

```
class Table:
    def __init__(self, key):
        # using the __ in an odd way
        self.__key = key
        self.__records = []

    # only using lambda because you must, it's pointless
    contains_key = lambda self, record: any(all(record[f] == r[f] for f in self.__key) for r in self.__records)

    def add(self, record):
        if not self.contains_key(record):
            self.__records.append(record)
        else:
            raise Exception('duplicate key')


t = Table(('product_id', 'customer_id'))
t.add({'product_id': 51, 'customer_id': 10, 'units': 9})
t.add({'product_id': 32, 'customer_id': 11, 'units': 33})
t.add({'product_id': 39, 'customer_id': 47, 'units': 2})
# fails
t.add({'product_id': 39, 'customer_id': 47, 'units': 2})
```

But if this is what they're teaching you, I'd look for a better class.

If I replace:

```
# fails
t.add({'product_id': 39, 'customer_id': 47, 'units': 2})
```

With

```
t.add({'customer_id': '13', 'product_id': '1234-5', 'units': 9})
print(t.contains_key({'customer_id': '13', 'product_id': '1234-5', 'units': 3}))
```

The result is `True`.

Comment: Hi, if i have a dictionary: {'customer_id' : '13','product_id' : '1234-5', 'units': 9 }
and try to do it with : {'customer_id': '13', 'product_id':'1234-5', 'units':3}

it returns false, but it should return true as customerid 13 and product id 1234-5 is already in the table

Comment: Not sure what you're doing wrong, but see the edit in the answer.

Comment: Wait, my bad. it works totally fine. Thank you very much and when I read this function I now understand clearly the pattern. many many thanks!